# node placement in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code produces two coil windings. If I specify them both explicitely, it works fine. If I wrap it in a foreach loop, they don't connect as they should.
I tried varying the line width and the preaction line width. That does not affect the mis-alignment. Can anybody see the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{coil/.style={preaction={draw,line width=1mm,white},thick}}%
    \newlength{\coilradiusa}
    \newlength{\coilradiusb}
    \newlength{\coilradiusc}
    \newlength{\coilradiusd}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\coilradiusa}{11.593 mm}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\coilradiusb}{3.42 mm}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\coilradiusc}{8.407 mm}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\coilradiusd}{2.48 mm}
        \newcommand{\iminusone}{0}
        \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,anchor=center] (0) at (0,0) {};
        \foreach \x in {1,...,2}{%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\iminusone}{\x-1}
            \draw[coil] (\iminusone)
                arc[x radius=-\coilradiusb,y radius=\coilradiusa,start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
                arc[x radius=\coilradiusd,y radius=-\coilradiusc,start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
                node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,anchor=center] (\x) {};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\coilradiusa}{11.593 mm}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\coilradiusb}{3.42 mm}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\coilradiusc}{8.407 mm}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\coilradiusd}{2.48 mm}
        \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,anchor=center] (0) at (0,0) {};
        \draw[coil] (0)
            arc[x radius=-\coilradiusb,y radius=\coilradiusa,start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
            arc[x radius=\coilradiusd,y radius=-\coilradiusc,start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
            node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,anchor=center] (1) {};
        \draw[coil] (1)
            arc[x radius=-\coilradiusb,y radius=\coilradiusa,start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
            arc[x radius=\coilradiusd,y radius=-\coilradiusc,start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
            node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,anchor=center] (2) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Comment: Perfect! Still don't know what goes wrong in the for loop, but thanks anyway

Comment: @mauricev `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` rounds the number, or better, it removes the decimals. That's probably why you had that little misalignment, since Maarten's solution helped you.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt Will you answer?

Comment: @cfr I use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` by default when I need integers (instead of floats). I know it truncates all decimals and leaves only the integer part of a float. But to be honest, I have no clue what the problem is here. My first guess was something with node names as `\iminusone` gives `0.0`, `1.0`, ... and `\x` in `1`, `2` but changing `(\x)` to `(\x.0)` dit not solve the problem, it even generated errors. So I did not write an answer because I don't understand what's wrong with the question. So anyone who can provide more information than my comment is welcome to write an answer.

Comment: @Alenanno The piece that I don't understand is, that the nodes are clearly recognized, but there is still this small mis-alignment. I would expect an error message indicating that "a node 1.0 is being looked for but not found"(because there is only node 1). But the fact that it does (kind of) connect does not feel very robust, specially because the '1' is merely a node name and not a numeric coordinate (to my mind). Any light on this would be helpful in understanding, but again: Maarten's solution did the job

Comment: The expression `(1.0)` represents a point on the border of the node `(1)` such that the line between `(1.0)` and `(1.center)` is parallel to x-axis. (Similarly `(1.north)` and `(1.90)` usually coincide.)

Comment: @Symbol1 I feel like I should have known this. I was too focused on the integer vs float to even consider this.Thanks for the explanation!